# Export Specific Sheets into Multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, merge, split, export

Really stuck with a macro I using at the moment. What I have at the moment is a marco that exports every worksheet into a separate workbook which is great.

My issue is I have columns linked to a another worksheet (“Mapping”) for data validations.

When I open the newly created workbooks the data validation links are all broken.

So I’m wondering is it possible to change this macro so when it exports each worksheet, it also exports the “Mapping” sheet into each of the newly created workbooks? Code I’m currently using below:

```html
Option Explicit
Dim MainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim NewWorkBook As Workbook

Sub ExportWorksheet()
Dim Pointer As Long

Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Range("E2").Value = MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'enhance the performance
For Pointer = 2 To MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count
    Set NewWorkBook = Workbooks.Add
    MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Copy After:=NewWorkBook.Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    NewWorkBook.Sheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With NewWorkBook
        .SaveAs filename:="H:\2017\Macro\" & MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Name & ".xlsx" 'you may change to yours
    End With
    NewWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next Pointer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("D5").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question for us? Your question currently stands at "is it possible?", which probably doesn't help you that much.

Answer (score 1):

Having played around abit I think you can change

```
MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Copy After:=NewWorkBook.Sheets(1)
```

To

```
MainWorkBook.Sheets(Array(Pointer, "Mapping")).Copy After:=NewWorkBook.Sheets(1)
```

Which preserves the Data Validation

Comment: On the above code is there a way for the user to chose the folder path instead of "H:\2017\Macro\". Like an inputbox ? File names would remain the same (worksheet names) Thanks

Comment: Sure, change to `SaveAs filename:= Application.GeSaveAsFilename` https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/535724-how-open-save-dialog-box-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: Many thanks. Final question I hope :-) If I wanted to exclude one of the sheets (Mapping) from being saved down as an individual file, how would I do that?

Comment: No worries, I'd suggest you add an IF statement in the line underneath where the For Loop starts e.g. `IF MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Name <> "Mapping" Then` You'll need to add an `End IF` to the line before your `Next Pointer` http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html